# Should we banish the 'User-Interface' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This question is pretty self explanatory.

Should we get rid of the [user-interface](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) tag?  It bears many similarities to previously destroyed tags.

Answer (score 14):

**Yes.**

We're not designers, so even experts in this topic can't really use it in any way pertaining to our area of expertise.

Questions about the UI of a specific game should just be tagged with that game. [Questions about general graphics settings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80766/how-does-the-gamma-correction-feature-affect-my-gaming-experience) aren't really about UI anyway, and should be retagged even if we keep this tag around.

Comment: "We're not designers" speak for yourself. But seriously I'm slowly retagging these

Comment: @BenBrocka As a group, UI design is not our expertise. Individuals may coincidentally be UI designers, but it doesn't make questions relating to that any more on topic.

Comment: Just joking; though I find it more important the tag doesn't carry any real meaning for us; game tags explain the relevant problem space, UI doesn't. Being a game UI expert doesn't help me explain how to use borderlands 2's UI unless I happen to know BL2

Comment: So a question about how a games ui works, wouldn't be correct if tagged as user-interface? 

Example1: In Guild Wars 2, how do you draw lines on the map for your party to see it? That is [user-interface] and [guild-wars-2] tags, no?

Comment: @JClaspill No, because no one is an expert in game UIs in general. They can be experts in Guild Wars 2, however, which would also give them expertise in the Guild Wars 2 UI. The user-interface tag doesn't add any useful extra categorization.

Comment: @StrixVaria So, instead of 1 user-interface that is used in conjunction with a game, we want each game to have it's own [-ui] tag? Or would my example simply be used as a [guild-wars-2] tag and nothing further?

Comment: @JClaspill There is no need for a UI tag at all in most games. Some games might have extremely customizeable UIs (I think WoW falls into this category), and once we get a sizeable volume of questions about that specific area of expertise, a tag for it may be warranted. Sub-tags within games are generally argued for on meta once someone deems them necessary. Until then, just tagging with the game name itself is sufficient.